# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python

I am new to python. I want to extract the elements of array 'Address' from below json. I am trying to use map to split the elements using

```
r=<below json>
s=r["Customer"]
y=s.map(lambda x:x.split(","))
```

But I am getting the error as .....AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'map'

Can you please advise which is the best way to do this.

```
{ "id": "981",
  "Customer": 
[
  {
    "Name": "abc",
    "Title": "Mr",
    "Gender": "M",
    "Address": [
      {
    "Postcode": "2GF",
    "StreetName": "Black Street",
    "FlatNo": "123",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "xyz",
    "Title": "Mrs",
    "Gender": "F",
    "Address": [
      {
    "Postcode": "2CX",
    "StreetName": "White Street",
    "FlatNo": "123",
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but consider using the built-in `json` module to parse json instead of splitting values out of it manually.

Comment: What is `r` when you are using `r.map()`?

Comment: First and foremost: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Now: As Kevin already pointed out, you should probably parse the string with the `json` module first.

Comment: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map

Comment: I'm not aware of a single python data structure that has a `.map` method. Where'd you get that from?

Comment: `map` in Python is a "plain function", not a method on any object type. (This is inconvenient in my opinion, but thankfully Python has things like list comprehensions which are a very nice syntax for most mapping/filtering operations.)  Further, it applies to lists rather than strings - you could convert the string to a list first with `.split`.

Comment: I'm confused. Is `r` a string or a dict? If it's a string, then `s=r["Customer"]` should crash with `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. If it's a dict and if the value associated with "Customer" is a list, then `s.map` should crash with `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'`. In either case, you should not be getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'map'`. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: "I'm not aware of a single python data structure that has a .map method. Where'd you get that from? – Aran-Fey" check the pyfunctional and chained operators with seq

Comment: @Aran-Frey I am used to pyspark a little bit. so I tried to use map and split from pyspark.

Comment: Kevin, any references to built-in json module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just:

```
data = { id: 981,
  'Customer':
[
  {
    "Name": "abc",
    "Title": "Mr",
    "Gender": "M",
    "Address": [
      {
    "Postcode": "2GF",
    "StreetName": "Black Street",
    "FlatNo": "123",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "xyz",
    "Title": "Mrs",
    "Gender": "F",
    "Address": [
      {
    "Postcode": "2CX",
    "StreetName": "White Street",
    "FlatNo": "123",
      }
    ]
  }
]
}


for item in data['Customer']:
    for data_item in item['Address']:
        print(data_item['Postcode'], data_item['StreetName'], data_item['FlatNo'])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
2GF Black Street 123
2CX White Street 123
```

Comment: Beware that without quotes the `id` key is the built-in function, not the string `"id"`.

Comment: This works, thank you. This is "id", apologies for typo. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to extract the elements of array 'Address' from below json":

```
[x for dd in r['Customer'] for x in dd['Address']]
```